# Migrate firestore native mode to Datastore mode , Any Google Cloude utilty?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Migrating our database from  firestore native mode to Datastore mode , Any Google cloud utility

Comment: As far as I know, you write some code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can takes some downtime the easiest thing to do is:

1. Export your data (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import)
2. Delete existing data in your database
3. Switch the mode of your database (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#changing_between_native_mode_and_datastore_mode)
4. Import data back into your database .

Comment: Sounds simple. Has someone tried it out?